# How to set the right place that I want for my Shopify Section?

Tags: php, shopify, liquid

As a shopify beginner, I'm wondering how the sections are placed where they are through the files.For example, I'm programming a shopping website of a brand.On top of the main page,there's a header listing some product series ,where I can look through every product of the series when the mouse hover on its name.And by clicking the thumbnail I enter the description page of one product.Now I have a section called "section-1" which I want to place in some space of the product page...

I have tried adding

```
{% section 'section-1' %}
```

to *theme.liquid*,just under `<main>...{{content_for_layout}}...</main>` ,but in this way,the section will show of all pages.I only want it to show in the description page of a certain product.

So please tell me how to add my section to some place I want,thanks.

BTW,Im not an English speaker, so my description may not be so professional and clear.....sorry for that......

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to accomplish it (from the content editing perspective) but because the question is how to limit section rendering based on template and product the answer is:

```
{% if template.name == 'product' and product.id == 123456789 %}
  {% section 'section-1' %}
{% endif %}
```

If you put it anywhere inside theme.liquid (or any other place) it will show only if the condition is true.

Note `product.id` is not the only option. You can use more product object properties in your if statement: [Product object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product)

Other options you could try are:

1. [Using metafields](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/metafields) and rendering them based on content availability
2. Using a mix of dynamic sections in 2.0 theme and metafields